# How to make the left colum match the height of the text

Tags: jquery, css, alignment

as seen on image reference, i like to write a jQuery function to check the height of the text at the right and make the image height match it to "push" text alignment to right (see red box) how do you do that ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use another div and make it `display:table;`. That is what works for me.